# Inequality of cardinals: $AB<A^B$ for $B\geq |\mathbb{N}|$

Tags: inequality, cardinals

Let $A$ and $B$ be cardinal numbers. Assume $B\geq |\mathbb{N}|$. Is there an easy proof of
$$
AB<A^B?
$$
(Note the strict inequality!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as equality can be obtained:

Let $A:= 2^\omega$ (continuum) and let $B:= \omega$. 
Then $AB=\max(A, B) = A$ and $A^B= 2^{\omega\cdot\omega} = A$.